# Template help for notes

Tags: templates, notes

I'm looking for a template that is similar to the [Mathematics for machine learning book](https://mml-book.github.io/book/mml-book.pdf), but for notes. The fonts, spacing and overall structure are both sober and efficient. Sadly, it's not open afaik.

Ideally, the template would have wide margins to allow graphs or annotations as well as special colored boxes for Examples, theorems, conclusions, etc.

I'd like to clean up some of my notes in the future but I'm not proficient at LaTeX which make creating my own styles or classes really difficult.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Currently your question is extremely broad and also a bit unclear. Since you mention colored boxes for examples: take a look at the `tcolorbox` package. For the wide margins with notes in them, the `marginnote` package could be useful.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks ! I I realize this is a bit vague, but without the original template of the book I'm a bit lost. What I'm looking for is a good style file which provides similar structure and typesetting to the book. I also opened an issue on their Github s.t I can try something out myself. How can I make the question better ?

Comment: Probably `\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text using the \lipsum command

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem{myexample}{Example}%
{colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{myexample}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{myexample}{title}{intext}
Example contents
\end{myexample}

\lipsum[1]

\marginpar{
\begin{myexample}{title}{inmargin}
Example box in the margin
\end{myexample}
}
\lipsum[1]

\marginpar{A short example text that is placed in the margin.}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}` can serve as a place to start from.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll see if I can consolidate this with other stuff I like